# Can't define string literal in template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to define a new string literal within the template arguments of a function.

```
template<const char* msg>
const char* function()
{
    return msg;
}
int main()
{
    function<"why doesnt this work?">()
    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I have to do something like this

```
constexpr char msg[] = "this is ugly and annoying";
int main()
{
    function<msg>()
    return 0;
}
```

This is extremely inconvenient. I'm trying to create a printf-like function but this is a major hurdle. If I go to a fake string (e.g. `tuple('a','b','c'...`) then it makes the interface for extending user-defined formats harder and more ugly as well as the code in general. (%d%,%f%,%e% are default formats, %myformat% is an user-defined example. They can be as long as they want because of the % terminator)

How can I have my cake and eat it too (or at least as close to it as possible)?

Comment: Very very soon we'll be able to have string constants in template arguments. Until then, your const char* must be static or live at file scope.

Comment: The alternative is to pass an array or tuple of chars like you mention, though I think there are other StackOverflow answers that say as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't allowed by the C++ standard because compilers had issues with what the rules for "folding" identical strings would work like, exactly.

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) we'll have deduction guides, and non-type template arguments of user provised class type.  Instead of a `char const*` you'll take a `ct_string` initialized by `"some string"` that will contain its string data and use `<=>` to determine uniqueness.

Until then you are out of luck.

Note that you get a distinct `function<msg>()` for each buffer `msg` used, not for each string value.